# Hyperledger fabric Crypto materials

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

If we see the **crypto-config** folder in **basic-network** of **fabric-sample**, we have various certificate materials with various types:

```
└── example.com
├── ca
│   ├── 0d46ccf0e9436c1bc3b6e2bf80cdb202c4943604f95c72ee0ff839d3ec300719_sk
│   └── ca.example.com-cert.pem
├── msp
│   ├── admincerts
│   │   └── Admin@example.com-cert.pem
│   ├── cacerts
│   │   └── ca.example.com-cert.pem
│   └── tlscacerts
│       └── tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
├── orderers
│   └── orderer.example.com
│       ├── msp
│       │   ├── admincerts
│       │   │   └── Admin@example.com-cert.pem
│       │   ├── cacerts
│       │   │   └── ca.example.com-cert.pem
│       │   ├── keystore
│       │   │   └── 2fb065725bf1b7e2811c0e8ca8d37f5a951fc4cd1162a47aad8accf9ddd10291_sk
│       │   ├── signcerts
│       │   │   └── orderer.example.com-cert.pem
│       │   └── tlscacerts
│       │       └── tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
│       └── tls
│           ├── ca.crt
│           ├── server.crt
│           └── server.key
├── tlsca
│   ├── 6a211ed18880b4db3867831c977809902713b8e321a5ab55ecc104dafc2eec49_sk
│   └── tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
└── users
    └── Admin@example.com
        ├── msp
        │   ├── admincerts
        │   │   └── Admin@example.com-cert.pem
        │   ├── cacerts
        │   │   └── ca.example.com-cert.pem
        │   ├── keystore
        │   │   └── db670eed8487a93c35ae448b9f84c2f241a7a8c87df0544fc1dc08baf7832aa0_sk
        │   ├── signcerts
        │   │   └── Admin@example.com-cert.pem
        │   └── tlscacerts
        │       └── tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
        └── tls
            ├── ca.crt
            ├── server.crt
            └── server.key
```

Can anyone explain why there are so too many of these files why are some of these files duplicated(such as **ca.example.com-cert.pem** have many copies) and there purpose.
What are **.pem** files used for?
What are **.crt** files used for?
What are **.key** files used for?
What are ** ...._sk** files used for?

And why the **fabcar** example manage it only by using 3 files.??

```
fabcar/creds
├── 5890f0061619c06fb29dea8cb304edecc020fe63f41a6db109f1e227cc1cb2a8-priv
├── 5890f0061619c06fb29dea8cb304edecc020fe63f41a6db109f1e227cc1cb2a8-pub
└── PeerAdmin
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: You can find your answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60100493/7550476

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each Organization requires a unique root certificate (ca-cert), that binds specific components (peers and orderers) to that organization.

Transactions and communications within Fabric are signed by an entity's private key (keystore), and then verified by means of a public key (signcerts).

As different organization also required to communicate or share their ledger so there is need of CA or MSP on organization level. Within each organization we can have multiple peers so we need certification for these peers too. Even peers from different organizations can join each other so signcerts(for authenticating) and TLScerts(for a secure handshake).

To have a look how these are generate i suggest you to Manually generate the artifacts

http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html

and see the different certs in the folders inside as you created them.

These are keys used by fabcar to generate the above mentioned certificates.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer.
I have read through docs but still confused.
How we can grasp 3 files, like fabcar is using,  from the whole certificate hierarchy generated by cryptogen. 
And what files we need to use in our NodeJS SDK to authenticate and validate the peer, from certificates generated by cryptogen.

Comment: Each participate(e.g. root certificate, peers, orderer etc) that want to interact with ledger have to pass its certificate. These certificates get store by default in crypto-config folder. Use the following to link to learn about creating certificates and using them in configuration. http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release/build_network.html

Comment: Can you please make a tree diagram of all the folders in crypto-config and add a description against each folder about what it is for? It will be really helpful if we can have something like that as it is very confusing. I am facing an issue for 3 days now because I am not using the right certs and I have tried all the P&Cs of the certs. If you can document it somewhere like in a medium article or anything, it will save a lot of time. @kots